# Getting syntax error in Label Expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I am receiving the SyntaxError: invalid syntax(string, line 26)(last line in this case) when I am trying to make this label expression for use in ArcMap. As far as I can see, everything looks right. I believe the indentations are correct and I've tried them in a few different places to make sure. Any ideas?

```
def FindLabel ( [SWSID] ):
  import arcpy
  myDataTable = "Muskoka_100miRadial_Combined" #insert data table name
  myComponent = "Muskoka Airport" #insert component name
  myScreeningLevel = "50" #insert exceedance  level
  myQuerySelect = '"SWS_ID"' + " = '" + [SWSID] + "' and " + '"component"' + " like '" + myComponent + "%'"
  myFieldsQuerySelect = "OBJECTID; Tavg_First; Tavg_Last_; Tavg_Perce; SF_First_D; SF_Last_da; SF_Percent; SD_First_D; SD_Last_da; SD_Percent; Rain_First; Rain_Last_; Rain_Perce"
  mySortQuerySelect = "SWSID"
  myText = ""
  mxd = mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    for table in arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(mxd):
     if table.name == myDataTable:
       rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table, myQuerySelect, "", myFieldsQuerySelect, mySortQuerySelect)
       myText = "<BOL>" + [SWSID] + "</BOL>\n" + "<ITA>" + myComponent + "</ITA>" + "\n"
       currentState = ""
       for row in rows:
         if currentState != row.OBJECTID:
            currentState = row.OBJECTID
         if float(row.SF_Percent_Comp) <= float(myScreeningLevel):
           myText = myText + str(int(row.Tavg_First)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Tavg_Last_)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Tavg_Perce)) + "</CLR></BOL> " + "\n" + str(int(row.SF_First_D)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SF_Last_da)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SF_Percent)) + "<BOL><CLR red = '255'>" + "\n"+ str(int(row.SD_First_D)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SD_Last_da)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SD_Percent)) + "</CLR></BOL> " + "\n" + str(int(row.Rain_First)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Rain_Last_)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Rain_Perce)) + "</CLR></BOL> " + "\n"
         else:
           myText = myText + str(int(row.Tavg_First)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Tavg_Last_)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Tavg_Perce)) + "</CLR></BOL> " + "\n" + str(int(row.SF_First_D)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SF_Last_da)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SF_Percent)) + "</CLR><BOL>" + "\n"+ str(int(row.SD_First_D)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SD_Last_da)) + ' ' + str(int(row.SD_Percent)) + "</CLR></BOL> " + "\n" + str(int(row.Rain_First)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Rain_Last_)) + ' ' + str(int(row.Rain_Perce)) + "</CLR></BOL> " + "\n" 
       return myText:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing colon on the last line.

`return myText:`

should be

`return myText`

I don't see anything else that jumps out, but that's definitely the cause of the current error you're seeing.

Comment: Facepalm..... Thanks. Those are the worst mistakes. Left over from a copy paste.

Comment: we've all been there ;) glad I could help